# How to getting value from checkbox and spinner simultaneously at a time in android

Tags: android, checkbox, bind, android-spinner

I have checkboxs and spinners just like this:[image]

In the above pictures:  first spinner `asiaSpinner` have different countries and others `europeSpnner` and `africaSpinner`.

If I checked `Asia` and choose `japan` from spinner and checked `Europe` and choose `Germany` from spinner. then click `set Details` button. set Details both japan and Germany with respective information.

I want to set following field and save on database, what i checked. If i checked only one then one and if i checked all then save all.

[image]

My main intension is how to bind check box and spinner.

Comment: Edit this part of your question to make it more clear....If I checked Asia and choose japan from spinner and checked Europe and choose Germany from spinner. then click set Details button. set Details both japan and Germany with respective information.

I want to set following field and save on database, what i checked. If i checked only one then one and if i checked all then save all.

Answer (score 0):

Each spinner should have an OnItemSelectedListener like this:

```
Spinner1.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
    }
    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos, long id) {
        //  Get/set your info from the spinner here (depends on how you are populating the spinner
    }
});
```

And then just check the state of each checkbox:

```
final CheckBox asiaCk = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.asia_cb);
if (asiaCk.isChecked()) {
    // Set whatever data you need appropriately
}
```